# How to databind with LIST

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose I have one customer class and I just populate list with customer class like

```
List <Customer> lst=new List <Customer>;
lst.add(new customer(id=1,name="jhon"));
lst.add(new customer(id=2,name="keith"));
```

Now can I bind the instance of `List` to dropdown or Datagridview? If not possible then just show me with small sample. thanks

Comment: you can do the above , you can bind that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Customer> lst = new List<Customer>;
lst.add(new Customer(id=1,name="jhon"));
lst.add(new Customer(id=2,name="keith"));


myGridView.DataSource = lst;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: i would have posted my comment as answer, just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string name in lst)
{      
    //ddl - combobox
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(lst[name].ToString()));
}

 ddl .DataSource = lst;
 ddl .DisplayMember = "Name";
 ddl .ValueMember = "id";
```

As per above code you can set display member and value member :) Hope that helps

Comment: ddl.DataSource = lst;
ddl.DataBind();

Comment: can we set ddl's value member and text member in this way?

Comment: @Thomas - Your answer i've posted above :)